# How to update the column using two tables based on conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-update

I have two tables such as STR_IndentHeader and STR_IndentDetail.

STR_IndentDetail:

```
  IndentID         ItemID           ItemStatusID
  --------         ------           ------------
    1                22                 4
    1                23                 4
    2                11                 4
    2                12                 3
    2                13                 3
```

STR_IndentHeader:

```
  IndentID           StatusID
  --------          -----------
    1                  1
    2                  1
```

Here I want to Update the STR_IndentHeader StatusID = 4, When all the STR_IndentDetail.ItemID's ItemStatusID = 4 with respect to IndentID. Else I want to Update the STR_IndentHeader.StatusID = 3.

In the above tables, In STR_IndentDetail, For IndentID "1", all the ItemStatusID of the Items is 4. So we have Update STR_IndentHeader.StatusID = 4.
But for IndentID "2", One Item's(ie. ItemID=11) ItemStatusID = 4 and the Remaining two items ItemStatusID = 3. So In this case, we have to update STR_IndentHeader.StatusID = 3.
I hope it would give better idea. How to do this?

My Desired Result for the above tables would be like this:

STR_IndentHeader:

```
  IndentID           StatusID
  --------          -----------
    1                  4
    2                  3
```

Comment: I don't see how PUR_POIndent has anything to do with this.  You just want to have the `MIN(ItemStatusID)` for each IndentID in STR_IndentDetail, or is that a coincidence?

Comment: Here, I am passing POID as a parameter. I need to check items and indentid based on PUR_POIndent table with the STR_IndentDetail and then to Update STR_IndentHeader.

Comment: Is it a coincidence that what you're setting STR_IndentHeader's StatusID to the `MIN(ItemStatusID)` associated with it in STR_IndentDetail, or is that what you want to update it with?

Comment: No, that is not MIN(ItemStatusID), I want to Update STR_IndentHeader with StatusID = 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off the information provided I am assuming that you want the statusID in STR_IndentHeader to be the smallest ItemStatusID value from STR_IndentDetail for that IndentID.

If this is the case please try the below:

```
update STR_IndentHeader
set statusid = minitemstatusid
from
    (select indentid,MIN(itemstatusid) as minitemstatusid
    from STR_IndentDetail  
    group by indentid) id 
where id.IndentID = STR_IndentHeader.indentid
```

EDIT:

Based off comments if you want to statically apply an ItemStatusID of 3 if the statusID is not 4 then:

```
update STR_IndentHeader
set statusid = case minitemstatusid when 4 then 4 else 3 end 
from
    (select indentid,MIN(itemstatusid) as minitemstatusid
    from STR_IndentDetail  
    group by indentid) id 
where id.IndentID = STR_IndentHeader.indentid
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can do this using `CROSS APPLY` available in SQL Server 2005. Hope that helps.

```
UPDATE      SH
SET         SH.StatusID = (CASE WHEN DC.DistinctCount = 1 THEN 4 ELSE 3 END)
FROM        dbo.STR_IndentHeader    SH
CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT      SD.IndentID
                        ,   COUNT(DISTINCT ItemStatusID)  AS DistinctCount
                FROM        dbo.STR_IndentDetail    SD
                WHERE       SH.IndentID             = SD.IndentID
                GROUP BY    SD.IndentID
            ) DC
```

Comment: this query also update StatusID for the IndentID 2 in the Header table

Comment: Ignore PUR_POIndent table. Update the StatusID  based on STR_IndentDetail and STR_IndentHeader. Please wait I editing my Question, I hope it would give better idea.

Comment: No, I am not looking for generic query. Iam just specific with 3 and 4.

Comment: thank you siva. so far i haven't used CROSS APPLY but now i have some idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I tested it setting up a database with your sample data:

```
UPDATE STR_IndentHeader ih
SET StatusID = (SELECT MIN(ItemStatusID) FROM STR_IndentDetail id WHERE id.IndentID = ih.IndentID)
WHERE IndentID IN (SELECT DISTINCT IndentID FROM PUR_POIndent WHERE POID = 8)
```

Comment: it throws error such as incorrect syntax near ih and incorrect syntax near the keyword "where"